# directive scope binding inside dom not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created one directive

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .directive('testme', testme );

function testme() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                items: '=',
                testval: '='
            },
            template: '<div class="testclass"><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
            transclude: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            }
        }
    }
```

In My Controller I have

```
$scope.myvalues = {"name":"someting"};
```

HTML

```
<testme items="myvalues">
{{items.name}} <!-- this is not working -->
</testme>
```

I know that directly put this in template, I just want to know why its not working inside DOM, How to fix

Answer (score 0):

The function should be inside the scope of directive

```js
angular.module('App5')
    .directive('testme', testme, function testme() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                items: '=',
                testval: '='
            },
            template: '<div class="testclass"><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
            transclude: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            }
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo here, it should be

```
<testme items="myvalue">
{{items.name}} <!-- this is not working -->
</testme>
```

In $scope you are declaring 
    $scope.myvalue = {"name":"someting"};
but in directive attribute you are using

```
<testme items="myvalues">
```

So you should use

```
<testme items="myvalue">
```